# How to include a ManyToManyField in an email? Django

Tags: python, django, email, format

I have my code set to send the user an email whenever a new PurchaseOrder is created in the database. The email looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the Product field is blank. The reason it's blank is I am using a ManyToManyField and am not sure how to email that to the user. Here's my code for it:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product')

def send_email_on_new_order(instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    if not created or raw:
        return

    title_text =  'This is the title'
    body_text = 'Purchase Order System Details' + 'Product: ' + 'Vendor: ' + str(instance.vendor) + 'Price: ' + str(instance.price)
    email=EmailMessage(title_text, body_text, to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
    email.content_subtype = "html"
    email.send()
signals.post_save.connect(send_email_on_new_order, sender= PurchaseOrder, dispatch_uid = 'send_email_on_new_order')

class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price_for_each_item = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.products
```

Basically what I would like to include in the body_text of the email is: the ManyToManyField so it'll send an email to the user with 'products' and 'price_for_each_item'

Comment: A screen shot of an email isn't really required to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I apologize. I was trying to be as clear as possible about this post. I excluded a lot of the fields just because there is so much code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate through your products.

I think you can do something like:

```
for item in instance.products:
    body_text += 'Product': item
```

Although, you should really be using a template and the [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class) class.

Comment: It's not letting me call .products though or if I call instance.product it'll give me an error since it's a many to many field.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You should definitely be able to call `instance.products`. What's the error exactly?